# How do you undo bundle install --without

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How do you undo running

```
bundle install --without development
```

Right now, I have gems in the development group that are being ignored because I ran this once... (note that I have tried deleting gemfile.lock to no avail)

Comment: It still ignore the gems that are in the development group after this because this is a "remembered" setting...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The updated, correct answer is @caspyin's, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145462/292586).

My answer is still here for historical purposes:

> Bundler settings are stored in a file named `.bundle/config`. You can
>   reset it by removing it, or removing the entire `.bundle` directory,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> rm -rfv .bundle
> ```
>
> Or, if you're scared of `rm -rf` (it's OK, many people are):
>
> ```
> rm .bundle/config
> rmdir .bundle
> ```

Comment: as mentioned by caspyin, you can also edit the '.bundle/config' file

Answer (score 53):

List configs

`bundle config`

Delete value from config

`bundle config --delete without`

Add value to config

`bundle config --local without development`

Or you can manually edit the values in `.bundle/config` file.

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
bundle install --without ""
```

Ref: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/spec/install/gems/groups_spec.rb#L149-154

```
    it "clears without when passed an empty list" do
      bundle :install, :without => "emo"

      bundle 'install --without ""'
      should_be_installed "activesupport 2.3.5"
    end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... It seems to still remember what I specified in the past. Thanks though!

Comment: @JonathanLeung Which version of bundler are you using? Try upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```

Comment: please consider adding details on your post, code-only posts are discouraged here.