# Gem::LoadError for mysql2 gem, but it's already in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2, gemfile

```
Gem::LoadError
Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile
```

This error occurred while loading the following files:

```
active_record/base
```

This is the error I get on running rails server.

```
The mysql2 gem has been added to the Gemfile as well.
```

I've done `bundle install`, and tried restarting the server but still get the error.

Comment: Did you run `bundle` after adding the gem and restart the server?

Comment: @BachanSmruty: Yes I've done that.

Comment: Is this in deployment?  Have you run `bundle install --deployment`

Comment: In my case, there was a poorly executed "group :mysql, optional: true do". Deleted the logic and just included the gem hard-coded.

Answer (score 247):

If you have this error when upgrading to rails 4.2.4 (also with rails 4.1.5) try using this version of mysql2:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

Apparently mysql2 isn't still compatible with newer version of rails because rails 4.2.4 is pretty new as the time of answering this question by me 8 September 2015 so use the above line in your Gem file and run:

```
bundle install
```

You should be good to go

Comment: in the msyql2_adapter.rb, I find the codes below:

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
require 'mysql2'

this mightbe the reason why default mysql2 version 4.x.x will not work

Answer (score 27):

It worked for me when I specified a mysql2 gem version before the newest  one (0.4.0). 
For some reason there is a problem with Rails 4.2.4 and that gem 0.4.0. So, to solve the problem I just specified the previous gem released: 0.3.20 and it worked fine for me!

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
bundle install
```

You can check all the gems versions here: https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions

Answer (score 17):

Change to

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

in your Gemfile.

This thread on the official mysql2 Github says to do this. You need to declare that version number if you're rails version 4.x.x.

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/675

Then run `bundle update mysql2`.

Comment: Thank you! To be precise, you do not want `bundle update` as this will update all of your gems. The command is `bundle update mysql2`. Might seem obvious, but it's the wrong command and could have unintended consequences. (To revert from `bundle update`, run `git checkout -- Gemfile.lock`)

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error after an upgrade to Rails 4.1 and I managed to resolve it by updating mysql2. Run this in your rails app folder:

```
$ bundle update mysql2
```

Answer (score 8):

This issue may occur if you're using newer version of rails > 4

Do these two simple steps, it will work.
Open your Gemfile and find the below line

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

replace that line with a specific mysql version like below

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

Now stop the server and run bundle

```
bundle install
```

Now restart your server. It should work.

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 7):

Being Beginner to the ruby i could not figure out the line
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'

it simply means go to your rails project folder and then there is 
line for mysql2 it will be like 0.4* so you can change it to 
**gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'**

and as we have new definition, we have to rebuild the dependency so to do that simple command as explained on the top **bundle install**

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't load mysql2 gem because new version of mysql2(0.4.1) gem unable to load the mysql2_adaptor. This is working for me.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and this is because Rails 4.1 requires minimum mysql2 version 0.3.13, and maximum compatible with Windows is version 0.3.11.

So I edited file `c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activerecord-4.1.1\lib\active_record\connection_adapters\mysql2_adapter.rb` and changed line `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'` to `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'`, and it works so far.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed this:

```
 bundle config
 bundle config --delete without
 bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres
```

Credits:
[How do you undo bundle install --without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765007/how-do-you-undo-bundle-install-without/15145462#15145462)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't load mysql2 gem because new version of mysql2 (>= 0.4.0) gem unable to load the mysql2_adaptor. Can you try this?

`gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'`

Hopefully, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, installing the mysql2 gem local (gem install mysql2, bundle install) and adding the following line to the Gemfile:

`gem 'mysql2'`

Setting the mysql2 adapter in database.yml

`adapter: mysql2`

was also important!

Answer (score 0):

I'm brand spanking new to Ruby on Rails and websites but hears what worked for me.

I had to change my gemfile, gem 'mysql2' to gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
then in rails i typed bundle install
then i tried rails s and got errors
so then i tried bundle update mysql2
then in rails typed rails s, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, installing the libmysqlclient-dev.
sudo aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev
and later run bundle.

Answer (score -1):

I have previously installed mysql2 0.4.5 but that was giving me this error so i have installed another version of mysql2 by:

gem install mysql2 --version 0.3.20

Hope this solves your problem.